# How can I communicate with Oracle Financials api from .Net?

Tags: .net, integration, erp, oracle-apps

Oracle ERP exposes a set of API but does anyone know how to communicae with it? Is there any third party tools that could help?

Please note I am not interested in Oracle database but Oracle ERP Financials.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Get Data->Web" entry in Power BI Desktop or directly add connection information in Advanced Editor to connect to the API. There are some samples for your reference.

[Power BI - Connect to your secure API](https://r.redirekted.com/redirect?redirect_id=4c94746a414a80a00b4825dfb80e3f74&request_id=afbc7f73189ce93044043c18a5de3c3c)

[API Strategies with Power BI](https://web.archive.org/web/20210302034733/http://angryanalyticsblog.azurewebsites.net/index.php/2016/05/16/api-strategies-with-power-bi/)